# p-adic analogue of self-adjoint operator

Tags: nt.number-theory, matrices, algebraic-groups, sp.spectral-theory, p-adic-numbers

Consider the very well-known result that any Hermitian matrix over $\mathbb{C}$, say $T$, admits a decomposition $T = UDU^*$ where $U$ is unitary and $D$ is diagonal with real entries. I am looking for a p-adic analogue: take a matrix $A$ with entries in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ or some algebraic extension. Is there some condition on $A$ that will allow for a similar kind of decomposition? I couldn't find anything in the literature.

An obvious thing to attempt is to see if symmetric matrices over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ work, but unfortunately I think not. Take, for instance, $$A = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$ over $\mathbb{Q}_7$. The discriminant of the characteristic polynomial is $5$, which is not a square mod $7$ by Euler criterion, so the eigenvalues don't lie in $\mathbb{Q}_7$. A much more plausible idea would be to get something with eigenvalues in $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}_p$, but of course I would prefer $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

I would appreciate a reference if such a thing is known. Thanks.

Comment: The "hermitian" property is very special, due to the fact that $\mathbb C$ has a subextension of index 2 and is algebraically close. No $p$-adic field has this property.
On the other hand, a "similar" kind of decomposition is given by the Cartan decomposition. For any $p$-adic field $K$ and any $n$-by-$n$ invertible matrix $A$, there is a decomposition $A = C_1 D C_2$ where $D$ is diagonal (and can be arranged to have entries being power of any fixed uniformizer), while $C_1, C_2$ have entries in the ring of integers $\mathcal O_K$ and determinant in $\mathcal O_K^*$.

Comment: The hermitian world should rather be thought as something on the real numbers, involving its quadratic extension; for instance hermitian groups are real algebraic groups (purists: real points thereof) and not complex. The hermitian theory makes sense for fields endowed with a quadratic galois extension and is essential, for instance, in the classification of simple algebraic groups over the given field. For a $p$-adic field, there exist some extension of order 2 (a small finite number) and one can play this game, and there are nice classification results for hermitian forms.